# Encadenar Dataframes de Pandas con un loop

Tags: python, pandas

estoy encadenando Dataframes de Pandas de la siguiente forma:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

file = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith('csv')]
dict = {}
for file in file:
    d[file] = pd.read_csv(file)

df_A = pd.concat([dict['A_0.csv'], dict['A_1.csv']], axis=1)
```

si en vez de tener dos archivos (A_0.csv y A_1.csv) tuviera muchos más, ¿que loop tendría que crear para que me encadenara todos los Dataframes?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar usar el módulo [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) para filtrar los archivos. Es aconsejable que uses iteradores en vez de crear listas, diccionarios o dataframes intermedios que no vas a usar más.

Una opción sería:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

ruta = ''  # Ruta al directorio que contiene los csv 
archivos_csv = glob.iglob(os.path.join(ruta, "*.csv")) 
dataframes = (pd.read_csv(csv) for csv in archivos_csv)
df  = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
```

> **Nota:** No debes usar `dict` como identificador de una variable, sobreescribes a la clase `dict` y puedes terminar con resultados inesperados. En todo caso usa `dict_`.

---

**Edición:**

Si quires imprimir los nombres de los archivos, puedes prescindir de `glob.iglob` (retorna un iterador) y usar `glob.glob` (retorna una lista):

```
ruta = '' 
archivos_csv = glob.glob(os.path.join(ruta, "*.csv")) 
print("Archivos csv encontrados:")
print(*(os.path.basename(path) for path in archivos_csv),   sep= "\n")

#En Python 2.x cambiar por:
#print "Archivos csv encontrados:"
#for nombre in (os.path.basename(path) for path in archivos_csv):
#    print nombre
```

**Salida:**

> Archivos csv encontrados:
> 2.csv
> 1.csv
> 3.csv

O imprimir una lista con los nombres de los archivos directamente:

```
ruta = '' 
archivos_csv = glob.glob(os.path.join(ruta, "*.csv")) 
print([os.path.basename(path) for path in archivos_csv])
```

**Salida:**

> ['2.csv', '1.csv', '3.csv']

---

> **Nota:** `glob` no retorna los archivos en un orden determinado, si se quisiera ir abriendo los archivos en función a un orden determinado podemos usar `sorted`/`list.sort` sobre la salida de `glob.glob`: `archivos_csv = sorted(glob.iglob(os.path.join(ruta, "*.csv")))`

Comment: Gracias por aconsejarme  sobre el uso de generadores e iteradores, estos consejos bienen muy bien. ¿Cómo puedo hacer un print de los archivos csv sobre los que itera archivos_csv?

Comment: @Rg111 he editado la respuesta añadiendo una posible solución al final de esta. Mírala a ver si te sirve. Un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Dos preguntas: ¿a que hace referencia el * en print(*(os.path.basename(path) for path in archivos_csv),   sep= "\n")?, ¿para la segunda salida, en la que se imprime una lista, sería lo mismo hacer print(archivos_csv)?

Comment: El * desempaqueta la lista y le pasa a `print` los elementos como argumentos separados. `print("Hola", "Mundo")` es equivalente a `print(*["Hola", "Mundo"])`. Esto funciona con cualquier función: http://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/argumentos-args-kwargs/. En cuanto a lo segundo, la diferencia es que si haces  `print(archivos_csv)` se imprime la ruta completa, mientras que como se hace en la respuesta solo imprime los nombres. Es decir `["home/documentos/csv/uno.cs", "home/documentos/csv/dos.csv"]` vs `["uno.csv", "dos.csv"]` por ejemplo.

Comment: Genial, gracias por la explicación.